Scheduled reminders for changes in participant status
I'm trying to get my head around Schedule Reminders for events. What I want to happen is when someone registers, and their status is set to Awaiting Approval, an reminder is sent. That's working.
What I also want to do is have a scheduled reminder that goes out if the participant status is subsequently changed to Registered.
That is not working.
Is it the case that the reminder trigger is when the registration is first submitted, and that's that as it were? Or is there a recipe to do this that's escaping me...

By default when participant status changed civicrm send email to contact. Also may be you can use civirules for this action to send email.

Problem is Im not using the CiviEvents UI directly. Also the Events UI does not allow sending to a related contact eg Parent, as Scheduled Reminders do.  Im using Searchkit to alter the participant statuses. I do have a CiviRule that sends out an email - the problem is it's a generic email with no tokens for the actual event, or the participant status. I could do a email template that says we changed your status to registered, but the recipient would have no idea what the event was, unless Im missing something

Have you had a look at using CiviRules and EmailAPI to fire out the msg when a participant status changes? It may work for what you need

Thanks Pete. That was my first thought - trouble is Im not seeing how to put the relevant tokens into the message - ie the related event etc. So obvs if someone had booked several events they would want to know which one they had been registered on if you see what I mean
